# What caused these major drops in reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Two users with a lot of reputation, e.g. [StoneyB on hiatus](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb-on-hiatus?tab=topactivity)
 and [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r?tab=topactivity) have gotten a drop of reputation near 2022 (first one 7,000, second one 2,000). Is this due a user being deleted, and the upvotes that that person had given to the user have been removed? Or offering a large amount of bounties (unlikely in my opinion).

Comment: A former user, who was once also  a moderator, recently chose to delete their account. There is absolutely no trace left of that person's username anywhere on ELL. Although their numerous noteworthy contributions remain, anonymously,  when their account was deleted all their votes were reversed too.

Comment: If you check users' reputation from the time the account was deleted, you'll find others with more or less significant losses.  (I'm surmising that the user voluntarily deleted their account because they were a highly valuable member, but there's no way to be sure unless you are a Community Manager.)

Comment: It's because some users deleted their account. [StoneyB on hiatus](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb-on-hiatus?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=4) and [J.R.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have 3 bounties simultaneously, for a maximum of 1,500 reputation. So that rules out bounties; you can also check the [Offered bounties tab](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bounties&sort=offered) on a user's profile to verify.

Drops like that can be seen when a sockpuppet account or a voting ring is dismantled, but that's not the case here. It's very likely that this is a deleted user who cast a lot of votes. Luckily, both users have enough reputation that they do not need to worry about this too much.

Comment: General advice: use the search function on [Meta.SE]. That will answer a lot of questions you have about the network.

Comment: I think those drops happened around the time that Snail's account was deleted. She cast a lot of votes over the years she was a member.

Comment: @ColleenV could be, yes. I could look it up but that's information that I'm not allowed to share ...

Comment: @Glorfindel No need, I was just suggesting that the "deleted user who cast a lot of votes" was the most likely cause.